# Probability of one random variable being greater than another (pert distributed) am I right?

Tags: probability

I have a problem where I have a network with some activities running in parallel. The duration of the activities in each parallel are independent, and the duration are pert distributed.

What is the probability of one path being greater than the other?

My suggestion so far was finding the variance and expected value of each parallel (they are pert distributed). I called the duration variables T1 and T2.
So
P(T1>T2) = P(T1-T2>0) and then Z = T1-T2 which have E[z] = E[T1] - E[T2] and var =var(t1)+var(t2)

And then use the cdfNormal function for these values up to 0....
But is it right to use the normal function, since the durations are pert distributed?

Comment: Readers might appreciate knowing that a "PERT" distribution is a scaled Beta distribution. The answer to your question will therefore depend on how many activities form each path and on the actual distribution parameters (the general answer is "no" but there are many circumstances in which a Normal approximation will be accurate).  Therefore, if you want answers for a specific project, you will need to disclose the details of your distributional assumptions.  You might also want to enlarge the scope of your question and ask about how to do the calculation correctly.

Comment: Thank you

In the problem there are two series with 5 activities each,
A1-A2-A3-A4-A5 and B1-B2-B3-B4-B5. For each activity, eg A1, i have an lower, middle, and high value, eg L=2, M=5 , H=9.

I have to find the probability of A finnishing before B
I know, Expected value with this pert distribution is E(x) = (L+4*M+H)/6 and var(x) = (H-E(x))*(E(x)-L)/7

Comment: My comment was asking you to state exactly what those parameters are for all your activities. Your comment suggests you are using *triangular* distributions rather than full PERT distributions.

Comment: The quickest way to get a reasonable answer would be via simulation. Given you have a small number of well-specified distributions/activities, etc, this would likely take minutes. Also, any probabilistic approximation would likely be less accurate, and be far harder to obtain. Certainly using normals, like you suggest in the question, would be tragically crude - other than for the case where your parameters result in a normal distribution.

Comment: Ah, ok.
My values are
A1: 3-5-10
a2: 2-4-8
A3: 0.5-1-2
a4: 2-3-5

AND
B1: 4-6-12
B2: 2-4-8
b3: 0.5-1-2
B4:2-3-5

Comment: Please clarify, *are* you in fact using triangular distributions, rather than scaled/shifted betas (as one would expect from the mention of PERT)? If the second, how do you obtain 4 parameters from L,M and H?